# Doctrine query to update users table

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, dql

I have a form with the following fields:

- email
- password
- url
- responsable
- pais (this is a multicheckbox)
- role

And I've created this method within the Model_Users class

```
public function updateUser($user) {
    $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->update('Model_Users usr'); //aca estaba el ;

    foreach ($user as $k => $v) {
        if ($k == 'pais' || $k == 'id') {
            continue;
        } else {
            $q->set("usr.$k", '?', $v);
            //echo "Key: $k => Value: $v ||";
        }
    }

    $q->where("usr.id=$user[id]");
    $q->execute();
}
```

The problem is that this isn't really updating... and if I do something like echoing `$q->getSqlQuery()` the SQL query I get is `UPDATE users SET email = ?, password = ?, url = ?, responsable = ?, role = ? WHERE (id = 150)`.

I'm guessing I cannot use a foreach loop to get this right,... so what would be the way around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have a `Model_User` instance available then it should be for the record you are trying to update. Otherwise you just use a query. The `updateUser` doesnt belong on `Model_User` it belongs on `Model_User_Table` assuming you are actually generating the Doctrine table classes for each model (which i personally recommend).

To answer your actual question though it shoudl look something like this:

```
   $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->update('Model_Users');

   foreach ($user as $k => $v) {
        if ($k == 'pais' || $k == 'id') {
            continue;
        } else {
            $q->set($k, $v);
        }
    }

    $q->where("usr.id = ?", $user[id]);
    $q->execute();
```

As for setting `pais` that code is goign to depend on how `pais` is stored in the DB (what doctrine type is it - array, object, string, M2m relation?).

Comment: When I do that I get an exception. For example if I change the email roberto@galan.com to roberto1@galan.com I get `Message: Unknown component alias roberto1`

Comment: That would seem to indicate that `$k` is actually the value as opposed to `$v`... can you post a `var_dump` of the data youre iterating through? Also after looking at the docs for `Doctrine_Query::update` it would appear that your initial signature for the `Doctrine_Query::set` calls was just fine. I think maybe its been a problem with your array the whole time...